# How to use Index attribute of groupby clause using foreach loop in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to run two `foreach` loops. The first will use group by clause to group all element, then, according to that grouping, I want to run another loop using index attribute of group by clause. How to achieve that?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
foreach (var amount in
    Model.DebitCreditNoteEntries.GroupBy(x => x.AccountName.AccountHead))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= """use index attribute of groupby""" i++)
        {
           ////index attribute contains total no of repeated fields.
        }
    }
```

Comment: (int i = 0; i <= amount.length[i]; i++)

Answer (score 4):

If your inner loop is simply looping through each item in the group then the following should do it.  Uses `Count` property.

```
foreach (var amount in Model.DebitCreditNoteEntries.GroupBy(x => x.AccountName.AccountHead))
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= amount.Count i++)
    {
       ////index attribute contains total no of repeated fields.
    }
}
```

You could also do:

```
var grouping = Model.DebitCreditNoteEntries.GroupBy(x => x.AccountName.AccountHead);
foreach (var amount in grouping)
{
    foreach(var creditNoteEntry in amount)
    {
       ////index attribute contains total no of repeated fields.
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3020803 please consider accepting the answer that you found worked for you best.

Answer (score 3):

if I understood your question correctly then what you want is the Key of the IGroupable.
the Key is the value that you grouped by.

if you had a vehicle class where a "type" property could be "car" or "truck"

and you used GroupBy("Type")  then the Key of the group with all the cars woyld be "car"
 and the Key of the group with all the trucks would be "Truck"

```
  foreach (var amount in
        Model.DebitCreditNoteEntries.GroupBy(x => x.AccountName.AccountHead))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= amount.Key i++)
            {
               ////index attribute contains total no of repeated fields.
            }
        }
```

now if you need an actual index you could do something like this:

```
list.GroupBy(c => c.AccountName.AccountHead)
    .Select((AccountName, ind) =>
    new
    {
        Name = details.Key,
        data= AccountName,
        Index = ind
    });
```

this would be an actual index of each group. singe Igropable does not implement an index you have to make your own.

I am on mobile sorry for the poor punctuation and grammar.